# 'initializeMemory(as:at:count:to:)' is deprecated

Tags: swift, pointers, unsafemutablepointer

As is, I'm using the following code to set a value at an index of a UnsafeMutableRawPointer (the pointer points to an array):

```
ptr.initializeMemory(as: Float.self, at: idx, count: 1, to: someValue)
```

This works and sets `ptr` at `idx` to `someValue`. But Xcode is giving me a warning saying that said method is deprecated, and suggesting me to use `initializeMemory(as:repeating:count:)` instead. However, such method doesn't have an index parameter.

So, my question is: which function should I use in order to appropriately set the value of an UnstableMutableRawPointer at some index?